# How can I pass reference data from C# controller into a knockout view model so it can resolve an ID to it's text value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have c# classes that need to be passed into a knockout view model for look up purposes. Show a user status of 1000 or a role of 14038 is useless.

I need to be able to resolve those values to their text representation.

I've got some "reference data" populated in a database. On top of that are some T4 transformations which translate the reference data into C# code, for example:

```
public static class UserStatus
    {
        #region Members
        public const string ClassName = "UserStatus";

        public const int Pending = 1000;
        public const int Active = 1001;
        public const int Inactive = 1002;
        public const int Deleted = 1003;

        #endregion
    }
```

This class is then used throughout the code to assign values to a User class, instead of saying user.UserStatus = 1000 it's user.UserStatus = UserStatus.Pending.

## Now onto the issue...

CURRENT ISSUE

I've got a page that lists users in the system and one of the columns in the list is the user's status. Well that status passed from in the object is 1000 not "Pending". What I'd like to do is be able to resole 1000 to "Pending" in knockout. Problem is because knockout is executed on the client side it has no knowledge of my C# classes. Ideally I'd like to be able to pre-poplate a list in my controller with the possible values of a UserStatus, pass that into my knockout view model and have it loop through the possible statuses and resolve it based on that specific users status.

HTML Code

```
            <tbody style="display: none;" class="table-body" data-bind="visible: true, foreach: { data: viewData.ClientGroups, as: 'ClientGroup' }">
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: ClientGroup.viewDetails"><span data-bind="html: ClientGroup.Name()"></span></a></td>
                    <td>TODO: Bind Client</td>
                    <td><span data-bind="html: ClientGroup.StatusText()"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="html: ClientGroup.CreatedOnText()"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Creating and binding the knockout view model.

```
    var viewData = {};
    require(['main'], function () {
        require(['message', 'viewModel/clientGroupViewModel', 'viewModel/clientGroupDetailsViewModel'],
            function (message, clientGroupViewModel, clientGroupDetailsViewModel) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    // enable ko punches
                    ko.punches.enableAll();

                    var json = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, new IHtmlStringConverter()));

                    // I'd like to be able to create something here and pass it to my model.
                    var lookupValues = { blah }

                    viewData = new clientGroupViewModel(json, lookupValues);
                    var zdm = new clientGroupDetailsViewModel(json, lookupValues );

                    ko.applyBindings(viewData, document.getElementById('clientGroupAdmin'));
                    ko.applyBindings(zdm, document.getElementById('detailsModal'));
                });
        });
    });
```

In the knockout view model

```
   _self.StatusText = ko.computed(function () {
            console.log('user status');
            if (ko.utils.arrayFirst(UserStatus, function (value) {
                console.log(value);
                return value.Id == _self.UserStatus();
            }));
            return 'false';
        });
```

Comment: You can take a look here https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html... read through **Example 3  Drop-down list representing arbitrary JavaScript objects, not just strings**. Try creating an object with optionText as status string and optionValue as the Ids...

Comment: hello, I would like to know more about your goal, if you'd prefer to do this before going to the client I would suggest creating a viewmodel class with a property that resolves the string from the int, if you'd prefer it at the client you have two options: hardcode the values in javascript, or create an extra api call that returns that userstatus mapping class. please tell us what you want to go with? :) oh and a 3rd option, if your js-code is in the cshtml file you could @razor the mapping to js in there as well

Answer (score 0):

Please read my extra info questions but this is one way how I'd go about it..

```js
console.clear();

var $fakeAsync = function (api, result) {
    var isEmptyCall = _.isNull(api) || api.length === 0;
    dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            dfd.resolve(isEmptyCall ? null : result);
        }, isEmptyCall ? 0 : 50);
    });
    return dfd.promise();
};
var $fakeData = [
 {Id: 1, Name: 'foo', UserStatus: 1000},
  {Id: 2, Name: 'bar', UserStatus: 1001},
  {Id: 3, Name: 'stack', UserStatus: 1000},
  {Id: 4, Name: 'overflow', UserStatus: 1002}
]
var $fakeUserStates = {
 1000: 'pending',
  1001: 'ready',
  1002: 'cancelled',
  1003: 'banned'
};

function MyViewModel() {
 var self = this;
  
  self.userStates = [];
  
  self.loadMapping = function () {
   return $fakeAsync('api/fakemappingcall', $fakeUserStates).done(function (result) {
    console.log('mapping gathered');
     self.userStates = result;
    });
  };
  
  self.loadData = function () {
   return $fakeAsync('api/fakedatacall', $fakeData);
  };
  
  self.method = function () {
   self.loadData().done(function (result){
      _.each(result, function (r) { _.extend(r, { 'UserStatusText': self.userStates[r['UserStatus']] }) });
      console.log(result);
    });
  };
  
  self.loadMapping().done(function () {
   self.method();
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```